# NSArrayController selectedIndex changing to 0 after addObject is called

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

### My setup:

I'm making a tab-based application using an NSTableView to display tabs and allow users to select tabs.

I have an NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController (tableView.content is bound to arrayController.arrangedObjects, tableView.selectionIndexes is bound to arrayController.selectionIndexes).

[image: tableView bindings]

My arrayController content is bound to an NSMutableArray in my ViewController.

[image: arrayController bindings]

My arrayController is **NOT** set to select inserted objects (see screenshot)

[image: arrayController properties]

### My problem:

Whenever I call [myArrayController addObject:], the selectedIndex changes back to 0 (even though I have "Preserve Selection" checked). I don't want this behavior. I want the selection to remain on the same tab after adding or removing objects.

Has anyone run into this situation before?

Comment: I notice that you're binding the arrayController's Selection Indexes property to a property on the File's Owner called `selectedIndex`.  The Selection Indexes property of NSArrayController is an NSIndexSet and not an NSUInteger. I can easily imagine how a mismatch like that could manifest in the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Sadly, the selectedIndex property is actually an NSIndexSet in my File's Owner, though I agree, I'll probably rename it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Deselecting "Avoid Empty Selection" fixed a similar issue for me (my first inserted object was automatically selected). [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/setAvoidsEmptySelection%3a) that the NSArrayController will maintain a selection unless there are no objects in the array, which seems like it wouldn't affect an existing selection but it could be worth a shot.